# How to create a google cloud identity for any email programmatically using Java?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

I have a requirement of creating google cloud id for some emails programmatically using Java. I can create full google workspace account for users using Directory lib but for some users we dont require workspace account and hence we just want to create google cloud identity for them.

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you tried and the results plus any errors. This [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Link](https://support.google.com/a/thread/228719081/how-to-create-a-google-cloud-identity-for-any-email-programmatically-using-java?hl=en)

> You should create an OU in Google Workspace and set the auto licensing off for this OU. Then when you create the User, set the OU of the user to the one with the licensing off. That should then give you an user with only Cloud Identity License.

Here are the detailed steps for each step:

1. To create an OU in Google Workspace, sign in to your Google Admin console and go to ***Menu > Directory > Organizational units***. Click ***Create new organizational unit***, enter a name for your new OU, and select ***Off*** in the ***Automatic licensing*** section. Click ***Create***.
2. To create a user with only Cloud Identity License in the OU that you created, sign in to your Google Admin console and go to ***Menu > Users > Create user***. Enter the user's name, email address, and password. In the ***Organizational unit*** section, select the OU that you created in step 1. In the Licenses section, select ***Cloud Identity***. Click ***Create***.

The user will be created with only Cloud Identity License and will not have access to any other Google Workspace services.

Reference:

- [Add an Organizational Unit](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182537?hl=en)